# How do you dislplay a List of Positioned Widgets in a Stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to display a list (below) of Positioned widgets in a stack.

```
  List<TableDraggableBall> tableBalls = [
    TableDraggableBall(selectedTableBall: 'images/Cue-Ball.png', left: 150, top: 200),
    TableDraggableBall(selectedTableBall: 'images/8-Ball.png', left: 800, top: 100),
    TableDraggableBall(selectedTableBall: 'images/9-Ball.png', left: 200, top: 300),
];
```

This is the Widget that the list was built from.

```
class TableDraggableBall extends StatefulWidget {
  @required
  final String selectedTableBall;
  double left;
  double top;

  TableDraggableBall({required this.selectedTableBall, required this.left, required this.top});

  @override
  _TableDraggableBallState createState() => _TableDraggableBallState();
}

class _TableDraggableBallState extends State<TableDraggableBall> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: widget.top,
      left: widget.left,
      child: Draggable<String>(...)
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, I need to place all of the "TableDraggableBall"s inside of the following stack. I'm sure that this is something easy to do, but I have no idea what the syntax is to display the entire list of widgets. I have been stuck here for hours. I've tried for each, for in, anything I could find, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. (only been programming for about a month)

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return.....
     Stack(
      children: [
        Center(...),
        Center(...),
        tableBalls.last,
      ],
    ),
.....
}
```

If I put tableBalls.last in the stack, it works and displays the last ball in the list. If I put tableball.first, it works as well. What is the syntax to add all of the widgets to the screen?

I also tried doing this, but when I call displayAllBalls() in the stack, I get an error message of "A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'"

```
  List displayAllBalls() {
    List<TableDraggableBall> tableDraggableBalls = [
      TableDraggableBall(
          selectedTableBall: 'images/Cue-Ball.png', left: 150, top: 200),
      TableDraggableBall(
          selectedTableBall: 'images/8-Ball.png', left: 800, top: 100),
      TableDraggableBall(
          selectedTableBall: 'images/9-Ball.png', left: 200, top: 300),
    ];
    return displayAllBalls.call();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I had to use to make it work.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < tableBalls.length ; i++) tableBalls.elementAt(i),
```

In other words,

```
for(int i = 0 ; i <yourListOfWidgets.length ; i++;) yourListofWidgets.elementAt(i),
```